# How do I get a Logitech DiNovo Mini working?

Tags: bluetooth

Has anyone gotten this to work? I have tried pressing connect on both the dongle as well as the keyboard itself on the back, and still no go. Let me know if any of you have had any luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would try:

```
sudo cp /lib/udev/rules.d/62-bluez-hid2hci.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/62-bluez-hid2hci.rules

sudo vi /etc/udev/rules.d/62-bluez-hid2hci.rules
```

Then look for the following line:

```
KERNEL=="hiddev*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[34bc]" \
```

and change it to:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[34bc]", \
```

Basically removing:

```
KERNEL=="hiddev*",
```

If this doesn't work, I would then either restart udev or restart the machine and try. You may also need to edit

```
/etc/default/bluetooth
```

and modify the following line:

```
HID2HCI_ENABLED=0
```

to be like this:

```
HID2HCI_ENABLED=1
```

If you do issue the following command:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Once you do this it might also be a good idea to run:

```
sudo service udev restart

sudo udevadm trigger --verbose --subsystem-match=usb
```

and then try to pair again.

There was a forum entry on how to get this configured, though it is slightly outdated. It may help us narrow down things we may need to try in the future to get it to work. [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9574808&postcount=1)

Comment: that would help if you could. im already failing at the editing the rules sections. thanks so much

Comment: 70-hid2hci.rules has now been renamed in 11.10 to: 62-bluez-hid2hci.rules. I will add the directions that I would try... I wish I had one of those devices to test with you...